# My Rig changes position when I tab in and out of edit/object mode

Tags: rigging

I have been struggling to find a solution even after reading a thread about the same problem on this website.

So when I set the pose to rest position in "pose mode" and tab out to object mode, it looks like the default pose. But when I tab back into "pose mode", it changes the position just like the picture below. I am not sure why this keeps happening. I tried all the method I read about including applying transforms, clearing all transform data, applying pose as rest position etc. and nothing works. I really want to know how to fix this problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.